# Write a Spark SQL window function UDAF computes on the last two sorted rows

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

Suppose we have a data frame that has 3 columns: id (integer), isChurned (boolean), timestamp (long). Its content looks like this:

```
1, true, 1000
1, false, 1001
1, true, 1002
2, true, 1000
2, null, 1003
2, true, 1004
3, false, 1000
3, null, 1001
```

We'd like to write a custom UDAF that used by Spark SQL's window function. We will group by id, and within each group, we order by timestamp. The purpose of this UDAF is computing if any of the last two records of an id contain true.

For example, the output of the above example input is:

```
1, true
2, true
3, false
```

Suppose we are extending the **org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregationFunction** (open to other suggestions). In which we will need to override **initialize, update, merge, evaluate** four methods. I am stuck in figuring out "how to know which rows are the last two rows" in a bunch of sorted rows. I find it especially challenging to write the **merge** method because I don't know how does **merge** handles precedence.

Comment: Spark deprecated UDAF as of v. 3.0, and recommends using `Aggregator` instead https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Aggregator.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the custom UDAF?

```py
w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy(f.desc('timestamp'))

df.withColumn('marker', f.col('timestamp') == f.first('timestamp').over(w)) \
  .withColumn('isChurned_2', f.lead('isChurned').over(w)) \
  .filter('marker') \
  .withColumn('result', f.expr('if(isChurned or isChurned_2, true, false)')) \
  .drop('isChurned', 'isChurned_2', 'temp', 'marker', 'timestamp') \
  .show()

+---+------+
| id|result|
+---+------+
|  1|  true|
|  3| false|
|  2|  true|
+---+------+
```